# unable to save changes in our web application when running VB test script using testcomplete 11.0

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

I have Recorded a VB test script in TestComplete 11.0 and did some changes in our web application. when i was running the recorded test script, i didnt get any errors in log file which was generated by TestComplete but changes are not reflecting in our application.

Here is the VB Test Script:

```
    Sub Test1
      Dim browser
      Dim page
      Dim form
      Dim textbox
      Dim table
      TestedApps.XXXcm.Run
      Call Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Navigate("http://localhost/XXXcm/connect.asp")
      Set browser = Aliases.browser
      Set page = browser.pageXXXConfigurationManager
      Set form = page.formConnectform
      Set textbox = form.textboxUsername
      Call textbox.Drag(89, 12, -244, 6)
      Call textbox.SetText("admin")
      Call textbox.Keys("[Tab]")
      Set table = form.tableYYYYtable
      Call table.passwordboxPwd.SetText("XXXX")
      table.submitbuttonLogin.ClickButton
      page.Wait
      Set page = browser.pageXXXConfigurationManagerField
      Set textbox = page.tableDbfieldtable.cellColrubrik.textboxShortname
      Call textbox.Click(85, 12)
      Call page.Keys(" ")
      Call textbox.SetText("Mobileno")
      delay(5000)
      page.buttonSave.ClickButton
      page.Wait
    End Sub
```

Could you please suggest me on this.

Thanks and Regards,
Sailaja

Comment: Try replacing `SetText` with `Keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `SetText` with `Keys`. `SetText` sets the text programmatically and may not trigger some keyboard events that you application may be listening to. `Keys` simulates actual typing on a keyboard.

To always record tests using `Keys`, go to **Tools > Options > Engines > Recording** and change the **Record text input...** option to *Keys*.